# Rigorous definition of endpoint

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

As i take on my first calculus course, i find a little lack of precision in the definitions throughout my book and hope that someone here can help me on the right path.

Is my suggested definition of endpoint of a function of real numbers rigorous?

Let a be in the domain D_f  of f. a is an endpoint of D_f if either of the two criteria is fullfilled:

(1): There exists t in D_f and b not in D_f, such that [b,a) is not in D_f, but [a,t] is in D_f. (Here: b is less than a)

(2): There exists t in D_f and b not in D_f, such that (a,b] is not in D_f, but [t,a] is in D_f. (Here: b is greater than a)

Note that this definition of endpoint allows that t=a; (that a is an isolated point in D_f). For example, consider f (x)=(x^4 - x^2)^0.5   here, D_f is (<--, -1] U {0} U [1, -->). If we select t=a=0, then [a,t]=[0,0]={0}, and if we select b=-0.5, we have [b,0) not in D_f but [a,0] in D_f.

I'm using the book : "CALCULUS, 8'th edition, by Robert A Adams and Christopher Essex". Page 79. I believe that I am a little confused: the book states: " A point P in the domain of such a function is called INTERIOR point of the domain if it belongs to some open interval contained in the domain. If it's not an interior pount, then P us calmed an ENDPOINT of the domain. Is this DEFn equivalent with the one i wrote? Yes, i should learn MathJax. I'll look into it.

Comment: Since it appears you've been a member for a year, don't you think it's time you learned at least a little MathJax?

Comment: come on us latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see. It's *your* proposed definition, not the author's.

But in Calculus $1$, the main interest is the behavior of a function on subintervals of the domain.

So in that context, endpoints are just points of the domain which are endpoints of one of those subintervals.

No need to overcomplicate things by changing the definition so that isolated points are regarded as endpoints.

However, now that you've given the author's definition, it's clear that the author *does* consider isolated points to be endpoints of the domain, by virtue of the fact that they're not interior points.

As to your proposed definition, even if it *is* equivalent (without a MathJax edit, it's hard to read), how could it beat the simplicity of the author's definition?

Comment: You're right. :) It is a simple definition